# Duplicates in findContour OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and Python. I have been able to findContours and draw a boundingRect on the contours and saving them as a new image. I encountered a problem, it seems that the program is saving 2 images because there is a duplicate in the found contours. I have been stuck in this part, how can I avoid having duplicates?

Here is the code:

```
img = cv2.imread('2.bmp')
img_2 = cv2.imread('2.bmp')
input_img = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.55, img_2, 0.6, 0)
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(input_img, 158, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
threshold = cv2.cvtColor(threshold, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval2, threshold2 = cv2.threshold(threshold, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
blur2 = cv2.medianBlur(threshold2,5)
canny = cv2.Canny(blur2, 100,200)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canny,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
maxsize = 0  
best = 0  
count = 0
limit_area = 1000
number_name = 0
x = 0
y = 0
w = 0
h = 0
nuclei = []
for cnt in contours:  
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) >= limit_area:
        print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))
        nuclei.append(cnt)
        print(count)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        roi = blur2[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        outfile = '%d.jpg' % number_name
        cv2.imwrite(outfile, roi)
        number_name += 1
        cnt+=1

    count += 1

cv2.drawContours(blur2, nuclei, -1, (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.rectangle(blur2, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 7)
```

Here is the image I have been trying this program with:

[image: 2.bmp]

Comment: What you you really want to do: find all contours whose areas are great than TH, or just find the maximum area contour ?

Comment: the reason why i put a limit_area in there is to find other nuclei also not just the largest one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this change should do it for you.

```
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Also, you should do thresholding on a gray image, rather than a color one. The following lines of code will help you get a better result:

```
img = cv2.imread('nuclei.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(255-img, 100,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```